# Java sslv3 alert handshake failure - depending on access order

Tags: java, ssl

I have cacerts file into which a certificate for site xyz.com was added with keytool.

The application is accessing two sites with ssl: gmail.com and xyz.com

(cacerts apparently already had cert for gmail.com)

If the first access is to xyz.com, everything works, any combination of subsequent accesses to gmail.com and xyz.com works fine.

If the first access is to gmail.com, any subsequent access to xyz.com fails with the dreaded "handshake failure".

This is consistent on JVM 1.6 and 1.7, across platforms - Ubuntu Linux, Mac OSX, FreeBSD.

Play Framework is used, but I don't think this is relevant.